# Creating a Cloze Question with Multiple Single Choice Questions R/Exams

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-exams

I do not have complete mastery over R, but I am trying to use the R/Exams package to create different exam versions and I am having trouble creating a cloze style question with multiple single choice questions within it. I am doing this because I have a figure that is needed to be analyzed before answering the 3 subsequent questions.

I thought the syntax might be something like this:

```
Question
==========
Use the following gel image to answer the following questions:

![]("Image.png")

Question 1
Question 2
Question 3

AnswerList
-----------

* Answer A
* Answer B
* Answer C
* Answer D
* Answer E
* Answer F


* Answer A
* Answer B
* Answer C
* Answer D
* Answer E

* Answer A
* Answer B
* Answer C
* Answer D
* Answer E

Meta-information
===============
extype: cloze
exclozetype: schoice|schoice|schoice
exsolution: 000010|00010|00010
exshuffle: TRUE
```

I haven't found anything online and I'm getting stuck. If anyone can help I would extremely appreciate it and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Minimal example:**

You are almost done, good job! You just need to tell the system where the dropdown interactions should be placed within the exercises. You can do so with `##ANSWER1##` etc. rather than `Question 1`. Thus, when you replace the three lines

```
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
```

with

```
##ANSWER1##
##ANSWER2##
##ANSWER3##
```

then the exercise works!

**More elaborate example:**

A similar but somewhat more elaborate example that uses some more R code for randomization is shipped within the package and you can try it via `exams2canvas("vowels.Rmd")`. The source code of the file is:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
## Vowels and their quality
vowels <- voweltab <- rbind(
  c("i", "close", "front", "unrounded"),
  c("e", "close-mid", "front", "unrounded"),
  c("ɛ", "open-mid", "front", "unrounded"),
  c("a", "open", "front", "unrounded"),
  c("ɑ", "open", "back", "unrounded"),
  c("ɔ", "open-mid", "back", "rounded"),
  c("o", "close-mid", "back", "rounded"),
  c("u", "close", "back", "rounded"),
  c("y", "close", "front", "rounded"),
  c("ø", "close-mid", "front", "rounded"),
  c("œ", "open-mid", "front", "rounded"),
  c("ɶ", "open", "front", "rounded"),
  c("ɒ", "open", "back", "rounded"),
  c("ʌ", "open-mid", "back", "unrounded"),
  c("ɤ", "close-mid", "back", "unrounded"),
  c("ɯ", "close", "back", "unrounded"),
  c("ɨ", "close", "central", "unrounded"),
  c("ʉ", "close", "central", "rounded")
)
vowels <- cbind(vowels, "", "", "")

## Vowel quality parameters
height <- c("close", "near-close", "close-mid", "mid", "open-mid", "near-open", "open")
front_back <- c("front", "front centralized", "central", "back centralized", "back")
lips <- c("unrounded", "rounded")

## Binary coding of features
match_mchoice <- function(true, options) {
  x <- match(true, options)
  sapply(x, function(i) paste(append(rep(0, length(options) - 1), 1, after = i - 1), collapse = ""))
}
vowels[, 5] <- match_mchoice(vowels[,2], height)
vowels[, 6] <- match_mchoice(vowels[,3], front_back)
vowels[, 7] <- match_mchoice(vowels[,4], lips)

## Casually selecting two vowels
vowels <- vowels[sample(1:nrow(vowels), 2), ]

## Possible answers and correct solution
ans <- rep(c(height, front_back, lips), 2)
sol <- paste(t(vowels[, 5:7]), collapse = "|")
```

Question
========
Describe the following Cardinal vowels according to the three parameters
vowel height, frontness-backness, and lip rounding:

1. [`r vowels[1,1]`] is the ##ANSWER1## ##ANSWER2## ##ANSWER3## vowel.
2. [`r vowels[2,1]`] is the ##ANSWER4## ##ANSWER5## ##ANSWER6## vowel.

```{r, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
answerlist(ans, markup = "markdown")
```

Solution
========
For an overview of the 18 Cardinal vowels see <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_vowels>.

1. [`r vowels[1,1]`] is the `r vowels[1,2]` `r vowels[1,3]` `r vowels[1,4]` vowel.
2. [`r vowels[2,1]`] is the `r vowels[2,2]` `r vowels[2,3]` `r vowels[2,4]` vowel.

Meta-information
================
exname: Cardinal vowels
extype: cloze
exclozetype: schoice|schoice|schoice|schoice|schoice|schoice
exsolution: `r sol`
````

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try your solution out and I extremely look forward to it. I am very excited and extremely appreciate your answer. Thank you for your work on the package!

Comment: Hi Achim, I hope you see this, I tried your solution and it's almost to how I would like it. I want the multiple choices to be in the format of :
A)
B)
C) etc. 

But I'm getting them as: 
ChoiceA/ChoiceB/ChoiceC/etc.

Would you happen to know how to make it like the former rather than the latter? I failed to mention in my initial question, sorry about that, but I am using exams2pdf because this will be a written exam (and if this impacts the potential solution). Thanks again and I extremely appreciate any guidance you can provide!

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought this was for an online test. For a written test I would recommend to use a sequence of three schoice questions with `exams2nops()`. You can embed the image in the first question and then start the second question with something like: _For the graphic from the previous question also answer ..._ And similarly for the third question.

Comment: My apologies again for not including that initially. I will play around with the exams2nops() and hopefully not get stuck. The, hopefully last, question I have is that is it possible to randomize the exam except for specific questions? I've dug around a bit but I do not believe I saw a definitive answer. Thank you again very much!

Comment: I actually found a rough fix to associate the questions together while creating the exam. I included them within the template file as a .pdf, so when the exam is generated they come at the end with the figure they are associated with. Just wanted to add my solution here in case anyone runs into a similar scenario as me. It doesn't necessarily allow for the randomization but it keeps it all together. Thanks again for your help Achim!